# How to Write a 'removeZeros' function that accepts an integer n and returns this integer without zeros in javascript?

Tags: arrays, string, loops

This is the code i have so far but the mate academy platform rejects it

```
function removeZeros(n) {
   let nStr = n.toString();
   let nStrArr = nStr.split('');
   let nStrArrNoZeros = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < nStrArr.length; i++) {
   if (nStrArr[i] !== '0') {
   nStrArrNoZeros.push(nStrArr[i]);
   }
  }
   return parseInt(nStrArrNoZeros.join(''));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use below code.
Hope it would be help to you.

```
const removeZeros = (str) => {
  return parseInt(str.replace(/0/g, ''));
}
```

Comment: When parsing integers it is recommended to also add the radix even though it is optional. Thus, `parseInt(yourString, 10)`. Wasn't the question about the argument being an integer? You should probably mention that you assume this typecast to a string first. Otherwise good answer.